# setDataValidation not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running the following code in Google Apps Script on a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

```
  function testRiskArea() {

    // This test can be run when the cell in the Category column is selected, 
    // to get the RiskArea

    var tsheet = 'Base';
    var catCol = 9;
    var riskAreaColumn = 10;

    //var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var sname = s.getName();

    if (sname == tsheet) {

      //var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
      var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

      var scol = r.getColumn();

      if (scol == catCol) {

        var cell = s.getRange(r.getRow(), riskAreaColumn);

        var rangeName = getNamedRange("CategoryRiskRange",s.getRange(r.getRow(), catCol).getValue());

        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(rangeName);

        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
            .requireValueInRange(range, true)
            .setAllowInvalid(true)
            .build();

        cell.clearDataValidations();
        cell.setDataValidation(rule);

        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }

  }
```

The getNamedRange function is as follows:

```
  function getNamedRange(categoryRange, category) {
    //var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var categoryList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(categoryRange).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++) {
      //Logger.log(categoryList[i][0]);
      if (categoryList[i][0] == category) {
        return categoryList[i][1];
      }
    }
  }
```

The whole getNamedRange function works as follows: I have a named range on another sheet called CategoryRiskRange that looks like this:

```
Air         RiskAir 
Asbestos    RiskAsbestos
```

and then a bunch of other named ranges, of which one is named, for example, RiskAsbestos:

```
Environmental
Health
```

When I debug, everything seems to be working fine, the variable rangeName is returned without a problem, the variables range and rule both seem to be set accordingly (although they just show up as objects in the debug window), but the DataValidation is not being cleared or set as it should.

I really have no idea why this relatively simple bit of code is not working.  Perhaps there is something I am missing that is obvious but I can't see it.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the clearDataValidations is not working, as the cell already has a Data Validation in it that is in error.  Trying to re-create the error.

Answer (score 0):

With the script you prepared, then you need to use `.requireValueInList()` and not `requireValueInRange()`.

If you loose the `.getValues()`, then you can use the `requireValueInRange()`.

See this answer I gave on Web Applications: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60887/29140